# How to Separate a Range of Odd and Even Numbers Through Searching the Array While Skipping Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

I'd like to challenge myself and develop my programming skills. I would like to create a program that asks for the user to enter a range of numbers where odd and even numbers should be separated (preferably through search) and also separated by a specified jump factor.

Also the user should be allowed to choose whether or not they would like to continue. And if so they can repeat the process of entering a new range.

for example when the program is run a sample input would be:

```
"Please enter the first number in the range": 11
"Please enter the last number in the range": 20
"Please enter the amount you want to jump by": 3
```

and the program would output:

```
"Your odd Numbers are": 11,17
"Your even Numbers are": 14,20
"Would you like to enter more numbers(Y/N)":
```

So far what I have for code is this but am having trouble putting it together and would appreciate some help.

```
import sys
print("Hello. Please Proceed to Enter a Range of Numbers")
first = int(input("please enter the first number in the range: "))
last = int(input("please enter the last number in the range: "))
jump = int(input("please enter the amount you want to jump by: "))

def mylist(first,last):
    print("your first number is: ",first,"your last number is: ",last,"your jump factor is: ",jump)



def binarySearch (target, mylist):
    startIndex = 0
    endIndex = len(mylist) – 1
    found = False
    targetIndex = -1

    while (not found and startIndex <= endIndex):
        midpoint = (startIndex + endIndex) // 2
        if (mylist[midpoint] == target):
            found = True
            targetIndex = midpoint
        else:
            if(target<mylist[midpoint]):
                endIndex=midpoint-1
            else:
                startIndex=midpoint+1

    return targetIndex

print("your odd Numbers are: ")
print("your even Numbers are: ")
input("Would you like to enter more numbers (Y/N)?")
    N = sys.exit()
    Y = first = int(input("please enter the first number in the range"))
        last = int(input("please enter the last number in the range"))
        jump = int(input("please enter the amount you want to jump by: "))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**question** - "So far what I have for code is this but am having trouble putting it together and would appreciate some help."

**answer** - 
As a start, it seems like a good idea to group your inputs and outputs into functions! Then putting it together is a snap!

```
def get_inputs():
    bar = input('foo')

def process_inputs():
    bar = bar + 1

def print_outputs():
    print(bar)

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    get_inputs()
    process_inputs()
    print_outputs()
```

You could even toss in something like `if input('more? (Y/N):') == 'Y':` in a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but couldn't you replace your binary search with the following?

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x%2 == 1, range(11, 20 + 1, 3)))
[11, 17]
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, range(11, 20 + 1, 3)))
[14, 20]
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do it through search? I was just hoping this program would help me wrap my head around the binary search concept.

Comment: Binary search should be used to find a certain value from a sorted list. You want all values that meet a certain criteria (odd/even). I don't see how binary search would help with that.

Comment: if the list is sorted as [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] it would work in theory.

Comment: But binary search is designed to return the position of a certain value. In your question you said that you want to print all odd/even numbers. I still don't see how binary search could help with that.